# setEnvironmentVariable from response

Tags: postman

Using POSTMAN, how to get the SequenceNumber value and set as  Environment Variable?

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<Response type="Heartbeat">
<Field name="SequenceNumber">270164614</Field>
<Field name="Status">ok</Field>
</Response>
```

Comment: is that the response body you posted ? can you post more information about your request's headers, etc. ?